# Заблокировать доступ для Узел сети через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, сеть

Добрый день. Как мне заблокировать не по IP а узел. Примерно вот полное имя узла ec2-34-202-158-62.compute-1.amazonaws.com IP меняют после блокировки. Можно заблокировать  как то так  .compute-1.amazonaws.com

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйтесь в саппорт амазона

Comment: Не  подходит. Все запросы к  REST API - каждый час по 100-200 запросов задержка 2-3 секунды.

Comment: Вы не поняли. Написать письмо "Пользователь Вашего сервиса нарушает работу моего сайта. Примите меры. Логи прилагаю". Конечно, маловероятно, но помочь может

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать ModRewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.+).compute-1.amazonaws.com [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

То есть отдавать всем посетителям от вашего домена ошибку 403 Forbidden

Разумеется, у запросов должно быть выставлено поле HTTP Referer, но судя по тому, что вы знаете, откуда приходят запросы, оно установлено

Источник: [Хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/165701/)